# How to differentiate between various usages of もの?

Tags: grammar

Recently I have a big problem with this. I have this massive sentence:

> そして、かけがえのないものといわれる人生の価値は、たったの三時間でわかってしまう**もの**であるようだ。もちろんその価値は、あくまで向こうが決める**もの**であって、普遍的な**もの**ではないのだろう。

Do all of them simply mean "thing" or does it mean something else? (like this usage: （「…するものだ」の形で）それが当然であるという気持ちを示す。「先輩の忠告は聞く―だ」「困ったときは助け合う―だ」) Because I feel like it can express something that is "natural".

How do I know which usage is what next time? Because for me in 90% of those situations, context doesn't really help. And I've been struggling with this a lot.

Comment: Do you know there is a (sub)category called [形式名詞](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E5%BD%A2%E5%BC%8F%E5%90%8D%E8%A9%9E)?

Comment: yes i do, what about it?

Comment: So もの doesn't mean particularly anything, or very vaguely just *thing* after all. Various uses can only be differentiated by [some patterns](https://www.jpf.go.jp/j/project/japanese/teach/tsushin/grammar/201206.html) or context. (or meaning).

Comment: What do you then think those もの's mean it the sentences i sent? If it just vaguely means a thing after all, that makes me confused about what to believe.

Comment: All are *things*, or translationwise maybe *that which* (or more normally *what*). - *a thing understandable in 3 hours*, *something the other side decides/what they decide*, *a universal thing/something universal*.

Comment: ...is it a contrived example from a textbook that forces you to think about もの? If not, it's terrible.  I can remove all もの and still convey the same message. かけがえのないといわれる人生の価値は、たったの三時間でわかってしまうようだ。もちろんその価値は、あくまで向こうが決め、普遍的ではないだろう。It seems that the value of life, which is said to be priceless, can be understood in just three hours. Of course, that value is decided by others and is not necessarily universal.

Answer (score 1):

> Do all of them simply mean "thing" or does it mean something else?

From my perspective, もの can have different meanings and what meaning you give it depends on the speaker / context of the sentence. With that being said, I think defaulting the meaning to "thing" is a good middle ground. もの usually seems to center around a singular object, entity, grouping, or etc of some sort from my experiences.

To illustrate this with your sentence above, let's go over the もの parts

Entire sentence for reference. 4 ものs total from what I see:

> そして、かけがえのない**もの**といわれる人生の価値は、たったの三時間でわかってしまう**もの**であるようだ。もちろんその価値は、あくまで向こうが決める**もの**であって、普遍的な**もの**ではないのだろう。

1. Here もの can mean thing, one thing, or etc.

> かけがえのない**もの**といわれる人生の価値
>
> A.) The value of a human life, which is said to be a irreplaceable **thing**.
>
> B.) The value of a human life is said to be **one thing** that is irreplaceable.

2. Here もの can mean thing, everything, or etc

> たったの三時間でわかってしまう**もの**であるようだ
>
> A.) A **thing** that seems to be understood (completely / in full) in just 3 hours.
>
> B.) With only 3 hours, it seems like **everything** is understood (completely / in full).

3. Here もの can mean thing, something, or etc

> あくまで向こうが決める**もの**であって
>
> A.) It's a **thing**, which is decided by another (group / person) in the end.
>
> B.) It's **something**, which is decided by another (group / person) in the end.

4. Here もの can mean thing, way, or etc

> 普遍的な**もの**ではないのだろう。
>
> A.) Perhaps it's not a universal **thing**.
>
> B.) There seems to be no universal **way**.
>
> C.) Perhaps it's not universal.
>
> Bonus: we don't even have to give a word meaning / translate もの for C. In this case もの could be seen as an emphasizing effect.

We can then take all of these parts and combine them to get an overall idea of what is being said / the meaning of this:

> そして、かけがえのない**もの**といわれる人生の価値は、たったの三時間でわかってしまう**もの**であるようだ。もちろんその価値は、あくまで向こうが決める**もの**であって、普遍的な**もの**ではないのだろう。
>
> And thus, the value of a human life is said to be **one thing** that is irreplaceable, a **thing** that seems to be understood (completely / in full) in just 3 hours. Certainly, this value is **something** that is decided by another (group / person) in the end and perhaps it's not universal.

You mention:

> How do I know which usage is what next time? Because for me in 90% of those situations, context doesn't really help.

Context will always play some sort of factor, because at the end of the day you are translating here. And because of that, don't forget (it's an easy thing to forget) or become very comfortable with the fact that not everything has a 1 to 1 translation. Sometimes you have to choose what's best or makes the most sense depending on your target audience, which can include yourself, and the context, speakers involved, or etc. Also remember, it's only difficult now. This will get better over time as you come across more and more things and get used to translating